# Detect when Angular loads. Depending on the device you can load or not Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a legacy responsive page where it injects an external JS file to detect the mobiles and then loads Angular 1.5.8 (in mobiles only). The Desktop version of the page doesn't load Angular. I don't have access to this external JS file, so I'm not able to edit the Angular side and I don't want to use `MutationObserver` because of the expensive it is for CPUs.

I'm looking to detect from JS (or any other way) when/if Angular loads. So I can do some stuff in the DOM injected by Angular in the webpage.

I did try the `window.angular` explaining here: [AngularJS : window.angular variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883889/angularjs-window-angular-variable) but it doesn't work in the way @Alexey Katayev explains. Since the functions runs even without Angular.

Is there a way to detect when (or if) Angular 1.5.8 loads?

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on what u have, but in simplest case you dont need anything:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script>console.log('Not loaded'); setTimeout(() => console.log('Loaded'))</script>
```

And in app.js u have:

```
app.run(function() { console.log('Angular here')});
```

You get output:

```
Not loaded
Angular here
Loaded
```